# Getting exception when trying to fill data to datatable from excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, datatable, webforms

I have implemented a code to upload and get data from an excel file and put it in a DataTable. The code usually works fine, but sometimes I get the following exception when the method **da.Fill(dt)** is being called:
**External component has thrown an exception**.

Below the code I implemented:

```
Protected Sub upload_button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles upload_button.Click

    If Not (File1.PostedFile Is Nothing) Then
        Dim filename As String = getFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Try
            If filename = "" Then
                uploadError.Visible = True
            Else
                uploadError.Visible = False
                Dim filepath As String = savePath & filename
                Dim fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filepath)
                If fileExtension.ToLower <> ".xls" And fileExtension.ToLower <> ".xlsx" Then
                    uploadError.Text = "The file must have an excel type"
                    uploadError.Visible = True
                    successUpload.Visible = False
                Else
                    Dim postedFile = File1.PostedFile
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filepath)
                    While Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)
                        Thread.Sleep(1000)
                    End While
                    Dim constring = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""", filepath)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    Dim con = New OleDbConnection(constring)
                    Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con)

                    da.Fill(dt)
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As SystemException
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Could you help me to identify the cause of the exception and resolve it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, not sure how much help we can be, but in you're situation with considering the error message your getting, you might find the problem is not actually your code.  Perhaps the issue is the excel file.  Investigate if there is anything else locking it.  Make sure it has all the correct and expected info (Sheet names etc)

Comment: I have added another copy of the same file and tried it, but I'm still getting the same exception, I guess it's not related to the file. I try the same file, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: I'm still sticking with the problem is external to your code based on the exception.  Your code is pretty simple so I would thing that would either work or it wouldn't, not work sometimes.  That said, it might be something in in the rest of your project that is doing something like throwing the oledb driver into an unknown state.  Short answer though is we can't really help with this one unless you can identify a determinable pattern or event sequence to the crash

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. Do you have any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Another issue is sometimes the process sticks on this method da.Fill(dt) and keeps running on it without giving the exception, until I stop it!

Comment: Also when I close and reopen the project it works well. I have added this block of code but it didn't resolve the issue            Finally
                constring = Nothing
                con.Close()
                da.Dispose()
                dt.Clear()
            End Try